# Javascript: split a sting into objects

Tags: javascript

I have an email alert from Oracle grid alert email I need to read into objects.

```
Target Name=<a href=https://asever.localnet:1111/em/redirect?pageType=TARGET_HOMEPAGE&targetName=msjfksk&encoded=FALSE&targetType=oracle_database><b>msjfksk</b></a> <br>
```

There is a `<br>` at the end of each line so I tried to split the text by BR but it doesn't seem to be working.

When I log out the contents of the array all I get is the first letter?

```
var splits = body.split(['<br>']);
var i = 100;
while(i > 0) {
    console.log(body[i]);
    i--;
}
```

Comment: You are logging the body not your splits. `console.log(splits[i])`. Also the `split` method takes a string, not an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Also, why are you starting with ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using body to print, use split to print

```
var splits = body.split(['<br>']);
var i = 100;
while(i > 0){
   console.log(splits[i]);
   i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```js
var body="something<br>something2<br>something3<br>something4"

var splits = body.split('<br>');
for (var i=splits.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    console.log(splits[i]);
}
```

If you want the lines in the normal order, use:

```js
var body="something1<br>something2<br>something3<br>something4"

var splits = body.split('<br>');
for (var i=0;i<splits.length;i++){
    console.log(splits[i]);
}
```